# Insert throws method not found, despite collection being created and published

Tags: mongodb, meteor, insert

I get the following error in the console when I want to insert a document:

> insert failed: Method '/customers/insert' not found

Possible errors I've checked:

- Collection is created on the server:

  ```
  export const Customers = new Mongo.Collection('customers');
  ```
- Collection is published, because autopublish is on
- Collection is imported on the client:

  ```
  import { Customers } from '../../../../imports/api/customers.js';
  ```

Strange thing is, all the other collections I created using the exact same code work, but just not this one.

This is my insert code:

```
var CustomerInsert = Customers.insert({
            Test: "Hello",
            createdAt: new Date(), // current time
        });
}
```

Comment: Do you also import it somewhere on the server?

Comment: Ok I feel very stupid now. I totally forgot about that. Thanks!!